# AssertionError: Over-read bin/yolov2.weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, yolo

I've been trying to run [this repo](https://github.com/tugot17/YOLO-Object-Counting-API) on Google Colab. A few months earlier, I had downloaded and used this code. But now, when I run it I see this Assertion Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:528: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:529: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:530: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:535: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/linear_assignment_.py:22: FutureWarning: The linear_assignment_ module is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed from 0.23. Use scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment instead.
  FutureWarning)
Parsing ./cfg/yolov2.cfg
Parsing cfg/yolov2.cfg
Loading bin/yolov2.weights ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "count_cars_crosing_virtual_line.py", line 8, in <module>
    counter = ObjectCountingAPI(options)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/YOLO-Object-Counting-API/object_counting_api.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.tfnet = TFNet(options)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/YOLO-Object-Counting-API/darkflow/net/build.py", line 58, in __init__
    darknet = Darknet(FLAGS)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/YOLO-Object-Counting-API/darkflow/dark/darknet.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.load_weights()
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/YOLO-Object-Counting-API/darkflow/dark/darknet.py", line 82, in load_weights
    wgts_loader = loader.create_loader(*args)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/YOLO-Object-Counting-API/darkflow/utils/loader.py", line 105, in create_loader
    return load_type(path, cfg)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/YOLO-Object-Counting-API/darkflow/utils/loader.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.load(*args)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/YOLO-Object-Counting-API/darkflow/utils/loader.py", line 70, in load
    val = walker.walk(new.wsize[par])
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/YOLO-Object-Counting-API/darkflow/utils/loader.py", line 127, in walk
    'Over-read {}'.format(self.path)
AssertionError: Over-read bin/yolov2.weights
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed made the old self.offset to self.offset = 44928276 in darkflow/utils/loader.py. I found this error saying the expected and found value are not the same. So to find the offset I used the formula
16 + expected - found
to find the self.offset value.